# Difference between len and size

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

I found two ways to determine how many elements are in a variable…
I always get the same values for `len ()` and `size ()`. Is there a difference? Could `size ()` have come with an imported library (like `math`, `numpy`, `pandas`)?

```
asdf = range (10)
print ( 'len:', len (asdf), 'versus size:', size (asdf) )

asdf = list (range (10))
print ( 'len:', len (asdf), 'versus size:', size (asdf) )

asdf = np.array (range (10))
print ( 'len:', len (asdf), 'versus size:', size (asdf) )

asdf = tuple (range (10))
print ( 'len:', len (asdf), 'versus size:', size (asdf) )
```

Comment: Where did `size` come from? Unlike `len`, it's not a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: Try to make your code clear so that people can understand easily to solve the issue

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't define `size` myself, might it have come with a library I imported…?

Comment: It could be `numpy.size`, if you did a wildcard import (which you shouldn't).

Comment: @jonrsharpe After commenting out every imported module, `%pylab inline` and `%matplotlib inline`, it's definitely the line `%pylab inline` (and not even numpy itself), which is `Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib` and hence causing the error…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`size` comes from `numpy` (on which pandas is based).

It gives you the total number of elements in the array. However, you can also query the sizes of specific axes with `np.size` (see below).

In contrast, `len` gives the length of the **first** dimension.

For example, let's create an array with 36 elements shaped into three dimensions.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [2]: a = np.arange(36).reshape(2, 3, -1)                                     

In [3]: a                                                                       
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]])

In [4]: a.shape                                                                 
Out[4]: (2, 3, 6)
```

### `size`

`size` will give you the **total** number of elements.

```py
In [5]: a.size                                                        
Out[5]: 36
```

### `len`

`len` will give you the number of 'elements' of the **first dimension**.

```py
In [6]: len(a)                                                                  
Out[6]: 2
```

This is because, in this case, each 'element' stands for a 2-dimensional array.

```
In [14]: a[0]                                                                   
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

In [15]: a[1]                                                                   
Out[15]: 
array([[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

These arrays, in turn, have their own shape and size.

```py
In [16]: a[0].shape                                                             
Out[16]: (3, 6)

In [17]: len(a[0])                                                              
Out[17]: 3
```

### `np.size`

You can use `size` more specifically with `np.size`.

For example you can reproduce `len` by specifying the first ('0') dimension.

```py
In [11]: np.size(a, 0)                                                          
Out[11]: 2
```

And you can also query the sizes of the other dimensions.

```py
In [10]: np.size(a, 1)                                                          
Out[10]: 3

In [12]: np.size(a, 2)                                                          
Out[12]: 6
```

Basically, you reproduce the values of `shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy nparray has `Size`
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html

Whilst `len` is from Python itself

`Size` is from numpy ndarray.size

The main difference is that nparray size only measures the size of an array, whilst python's Len can be used for getting the length of objects in general

Answer (score -1):

Consider this example :

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]])
print(len(a))
#output is 2
print(numpy.size(a))
#output is 12
```

`len()` is built-in method used to compute the length of iterable python objects like `str`, `list` , `dict` etc. `len` returns the length of the iterable, i.e the number of elements. In above example the array is actually of length 2, because it is a nested list where each list is considered as an element.

`numpy.size()` returns the size of the array, it is equal to `n_dim1 * n_dim2 * --- n_dimn` , i.e it is the product of dimensions of the array, for example if we have an array of dimension (5,5,2), the size is 50, as it can hold 50 elements. But `len()` will return 5, because the number of elements in higher order list (or 1st dimension is 5).

According to your question, `len()` and `numpy.size()` return same output for 1-D arrays (same as lists) but in vector form. However, the results are different for 2-D + arrays. So to get the correct answer, use numpy.size() as it returns the actual size.

When you call`numpy.size()` on any iterable, as in your example, it is first casted to a numpy array object, then size() is called.

Thanks for A2A